# Xml transform as Excel xls

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel, xslt, openxml

Okay, so I've been working on an XSL transformation for some XML data through VB.Net. I have everything working fine and the data is saving as a readable .xls file. The issue is I receive the following when I attempt to open the document.

[image: The file you are trying to open, 'Test_Xls.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not currupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?]

> The file you are trying to open, 'Test_Xls.xls', is in a different
>   format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is
>   not currupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do
>   you want to open the file now?

I've been doing some reading and I haven't been able to come up with anything to resolve the issue. I have taken the .xls file in Notepad++ and stripped it of everything I can while still producing the error. I have this as the output from my transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Workbook 
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

    <Worksheet ss:Name="Testing Data">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Tests</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>

</Workbook>
```

[image]

Which begs the question.. Is there any way to produce a document that can be seen in Excel though an Xml Transformation without receiving this error message? I can't alter the registry and I can't use any 3rd party utilities.

Comment: did you try the extension .xml?

Comment: I've successfully been able to transform and export it as a .xml file without any issue. However, after a conversation with everyone else, it needs to have the .xls extension.

Comment: ".xls" means native Excel '97 etc. You have to tell that your output is in SpreadsheetML. So, try ".xlsx".

Comment: Agreed. Should be xlsx.

Comment: `.xls` is a binary format (BIFF8 format, I believe), so if you have a file with a `.xls` extension, Excel expects it to be in that format, and not be an XML file. What you are actually using is "SpeadsheetML". Try outputting your XML with the processing instruction `<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>` at the top. (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226687(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Okay. I've tried updating the code to export the file with the extension .xlsx. Now it shows me a new error message reading "Excel cannot open the file 'Text_Xls.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."  I also did try Tim C's suggestion to add the <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?> instruction to the top. This is already in my xslt file and I tried adding it to the .xls file itself all to no avail. It seems to me that this error might just have to stick around.

Comment: Try changing the format to "Excel 2004 XML Spreadsheet" (extension: *.xml). XSLT Stylesheets transform to XML, and this is the only Excel format that really is XML. *.xlsx is a zipped XML format, and it's of no use here I believe.

Comment: Just save it with an extension of `.xml`.  I was able to take your sample, save it to `testsheet.xml`, and Excel opened it without complaint.

Comment: It's looking like that's going to be my only option aside from living with the error message. Thanks for the input everyone, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since the problem seems to be solved, I've expanded my comment into an answer.)

The problem with your approach simply is, as far as we can see (we do not see any code, except for the output file): your XSLT stylesheet generates an XML document, which you save with an `*.xls` extension. This corrupts the file, in the sense that the content is not valid when interpreted as an `*.xls` file.

The file extensions discussed so far:

- `*.xsl`: a binary format, older versions of Excel stored sheets in it by default. *Not* XML.
- `*.xslx`: the format newer versions of Excel use. Internally, it is a zipped file containing several XML components.
- `*.xml`: In this specific case, the so-called "Excel 2004 XML Spreadsheet" (for Mac; "Excel 2003 XML Spreadsheet" on Windows) format, which stores a document as plain, unzipped XML. By the way, other Office products also know an *.xml format, e.g. Office Word)

Saving your transformed document as `*.xml` makes it clear to Excel that the content is neither the old, binary format, nor the zipped XML standard.

---

More details: Confusingly, the set of zipped XML formats for the Microsoft Office palette is called "Office Open XML" ("OOXML", [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm)). The plain XML formats are sometimes called "Microsoft Office XML" formats. The specific format for newer versions of Excel is ["SpreadsheetML"](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php).

To make this even more complicated, there is also "Open Office", which has a range of other meanings, all of them unrelated to Microsoft.

Perhaps you would like to have a look at a [history of Office XML formats](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2007/01/25/office-xml-formats-1998-2006.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) It's a suitable answer for me as, even though it does not fix the error, it sheds some light on why I, realistically, cannot fix the error.

Comment: @michael.hor257k For Mac, there was an Office version released in 2004, and the year was included in the name of the format. For the Windows platform it happens to be 2003. I'll try to edit and make that more clear. Unfortunately, "SpreadsheetML" can refer to both the zipped and "monolithic" versions of the format.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's really open to dispute, some people would argue that SpreadsheetML is the part of OOXML that is concerned with Excel. Others say that "SpreadsheetML" refers to the Excel 2003 XML format (the link you've posted above) - but then again, [Brian Jones says that SpreadsheetML has a zipped file structure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2006/11/02/simple-spreadsheetml-file-part-1-of-3.aspx). But please add your own explanation of the terms if you like - I'd be glad to finally understand this mess of names.